# replace string with another string by second occurrence

Tags: javascript

I have string like `"key-original-original"` and I want to replace it with `"key-original-resized"`.

somebody help me with this by using regular expression and replace function in Javascript ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace Also this is a duplicated question ;)

Comment: Hi. Can you post some code sample that you have tried ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP did not even google `js replacce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
var str = 'key-original-original';
var newStr = str.replace(/key\-(.*)\-(.*)/i, 'key-$1-resized');
```

Comment: Here is a pretty good tutorial on working with strings.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-split-and-manipulate-strings-in-javascript
I know you asked for a regular expression but there are many combinations to do this.  If you look through the quick walk-through I am sure you'll find something of your liking.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
      text = 'key-original-original';

    var t=0;   
    text = text.replace(/\-original/g, function (match) {
      t++;
      return (t === 2) ? "-resized" : match;
    });
    alert(text);
</script>
```